How to Move Focus Between Grid Columns on Enter Key in a Data Entry Grid with ComboBox Columns?
I’m a beginner in software development and currently working on a data entry grid. I’m using a grid control with 5 ComboBox columns (Column A, B, C, D, and E).
I want to handle the Enter key so that focus moves horizontally through the columns in the same row, and when it reaches the last column (E), it should move to the next row's first column (A).
Example of the desired behavior:

Press Enter in A1 → Focus moves to B1.
Press Enter in B1 → Focus moves to C1.
Press Enter in C1 → Focus moves to D1.
Press Enter in D1 → Focus moves to E1.
Press Enter in E1 → Focus moves to A2.

Here’s the code I’ve written to handle the Enter key:
private void HandleEnterKeyNavigation()
{
    if (grid.CurrentCell == null)
        return;

    int currentRow = grid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int currentColumn = grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

    // Move focus to the next column
    if (currentColumn < grid.ColumnCount - 1)
    {
        grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows[currentRow].Cells[currentColumn + 1];
        grid.BeginEdit(true); // Start editing the next cell
    }
    else if (currentRow < grid.RowCount - 1)
    {
        // Move to the first column of the next row
        grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows[currentRow + 1].Cells[0];
        grid.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}


Problem:
This works fine for basic cells, but I’m facing issues with ComboBox columns:
Sometimes the ComboBox doesn’t activate correctly.
Other times, the focus skips cells.
I want to know the best way to implement this functionality in a data entry grid with ComboBox columns.
Any suggestions or guidance on how to handle the Enter key effectively in this scenario would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
